# template functions not recognized

Tags: c++, class, templates, hash

For some reason, my functions are not being recognized properly. When I run my program, I get an error saying the function is expecting 4 arguments, and is provided 1. The code below is all one maini.cpp, I'm not sure why it got broken up into different blocks. But you can see that in int main() I call search(hTable). This is where I am receiving the error, even though it matches the template function search.
The error I'm getting is:

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4024:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:40:18: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
 search(hTable);
```

I thought I declared both functions correctly, but clearly I'm missing something. Thanks!

```
#include "wordList.h"
#include "grid.h"
#include "heap.h"
#include "hashTable.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void findMatches(wordList list, grid theGrid);
void search(int typeSort, wordList list);

template <class T>
void findMatches(hashTable <T> list, grid theGrid);

template <class T>
void search(hashTable <T> list);

int main() {
wordList list1;
list1.read("wordlist.txt"); //create 
int search1 = 1; //Insertion Sort
int search2 = 2; //Quick Sort
int search3 = 3; //Merge Sort

//Search function sorts the word list, then calls findMatches to find all words in the grid
search(search1, list1);
search(search2, list1);
search(search3, list1);

hashTable <string> hTable();
search(hTable);

return 0;
}

void search(int & typeSort, wordList & list) {
    string gridName;
    cout << "Enter name of grid file" << endl;
cin>>gridName;
grid theGrid;
theGrid.buildGrid(gridName); //build grid based on input
clock_t startSort, startSearch; //keep track of time
startSort = clock();
float insertionDiff, quickDiff, mergeDiff, searchDiff;
float totaltime;
switch (typeSort) {
    case 1: cout << "Insertion Sort: " << endl;
        list.insertionSort(); //call insertion sort on word list 
        insertionDiff = clock() - startSort; //print time from start to end of sorting
        cout << "Time for Insertion Sort: " << (float) insertionDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        break;
    case 2: cout << "Quick Sort: " << endl;
        list.quickSort(); //call quick sort on word list
        quickDiff = clock() - startSort; //print time from start to end of sorting
        cout << "Time for Quick Sort: " << (float) quickDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        break;
    case 3: cout << "Merge Sort: " << endl;
        list.mergeSort(); //call merge sort on word list
        mergeDiff = clock() - startSort; //print time from start to end of sorting
        cout << "Time for Merge Sort: " << (float) mergeDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        break;
}
startSearch = clock();
findMatches(list, theGrid); //call find matches to print all words found
searchDiff = clock() - startSearch;
cout << "Time for finding words: " << ((float) searchDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl; //print time for finding words
totaltime = clock() - startSort;
cout << "Total time for sorting and searching: " << totaltime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl; //print time for sorting and searching  
}



template<class T>
void search(hashTable <T> list) {
string gridName;
cout << "Enter name of grid file" << endl;
cin>>gridName;
grid theGrid;
theGrid.buildGrid(gridName); //build grid based on input

clock_t startHash, startSearch; //keep track of time
startHash = clock();
float hashDiff, searchDiff, totalTime;
float totaltime;
list.hashTable("wordlist.txt");
hashDiff = clock() - startHash;
cout << "Time to build hash table:" << hashDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

startSearch = clock();
findMatches(list, theGrid);
searchDiff = clock() - startSearch;
cout << "Time to find words:" << searchDiff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

totalTime = clock() - startHash;
cout << "Total time:" << totalTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}
```

Comment: Paste the error and the code which caused it in your question. We don't need the whole program, just the parts that are breaking.

Comment: @SamCraig You're definitely correct, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare your function as template one.

```
 template <class T>
 void search(hashTable <T> list);
```

But it's used without any template argument....

```
 search(hTable);
```